# Why have private fields, isn't protected enough?

Tags: object-oriented, encapsulation, access-modifiers

Is the visibility `private` of class fields/properties/attributes useful? In OOP, sooner or later, you are going to make a subclass of a class and in that case, it is good to understand and be able to modify the implementation completely.

One of the first things I do when I subclass a class is to change a bunch of `private` methods to `protected`. However, hiding details from the *outer world* is important – so we need `protected` too and not just `public`.

My question is: Do you know about an important use case where `private` instead of `protected` is a good tool, or would two options "`protected` & `public`" be enough for OOP languages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Clean Code suggesting avoiding protected variables?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/162643/why-is-clean-code-suggesting-avoiding-protected-variables)

Comment: To downvoters: While I also strongly disagree with the OP's premises, I am upvoting this question because it is perfectly coherent and worth answering. Yes, the OP needs to be told why this is wrong, but the way to do that is to *write an answer* (or suggest edits to existing answers), not to downvote just because he hasn't figured it out for himself yet.

Comment: Derived classes are part of the outer world.

Comment: Don't forget that protected doesn't always mean access is locked to the inheritance hierarchy. In Java, it grants package level access also.

Comment: "sooner or later, you are going to make a subclass of a class and in that case" - Ähm ... no.

Comment: I have voted to close as too board, as this can not be answers in a way that makes sense for ALL object oriented languages.

Comment: Encapsulation means you have to use less brain ram when you develop.

Comment: I see many comments in our code: "// need to make this protected because ...". And I've had change to protected often enough. However, if we (and y'all out there!) simply had better classes - really sticking the Single Responsibility Principle - then other mechanisms and design patterns could more effectively address extendability issues.

Comment: My professor used to say that "There are things I wouldn't tell my children. Those I my private fields."

Comment: Does `protected` in general imply it is also visible to the package, or is this only a Java thing?

Comment: @CaptainMan C# `protected` implies only accessible to the class and its descendants. Swift doesn't have a `protected`, but its `internal` behaves like the `protected` you describe. [If you wanna read Apple's devblog on it](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=11), it actually makes a pretty good case for both why they called it `internal` and why the inheritance-based `protected` is pretty meh

Comment: It might interest you to learn that Python doesn't have a concept of `private` or `protected`. There is a naming convention for warning callers of your code not to mess with stuff, but there's no actual prevention. This sounds insane if you are coming from a language like Java or C# that does have these and encourages you to use them, but if you give it a chance, you'll find that it's not really that big a deal. Note that this *doesn't* mean that Python programmers recommend leveraging this fact in normal situations. It just means you need to know what is a good idea and what's stupid.

Comment: @jpmc26 Actually another note with that, it doesn't really warn it so much as Python will not help the coder discover/access/understand any member that starts with.... One underscore? It's been a while.

Comment: @abluejelly Yes, single underscore, double underscore in front for name mangling, double underscore in front and at the end for magic methods. It depends on how you look. If you do `dir(o)` on anything, you'll get everything (even the name mangled attributes and magic methods). I think you're thinking of `from x import *` statements, which don't import attributes on the module starting with an underscore.

Comment: @jpmc26 Couldda sworn there was a `man` or `help` or something that just printed the `__doc__`, but failed on hidden. But I very well might be thinking `from x import *`. Was a long time ago that I messed with python.

Comment: don't remove this please... http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com.au/2010/07/wikileaks-to-leak-5000-open-source-java.html

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18168410/1394393

Comment: You can make any protected method be "public" by inheriting the class and in the child make a public method which calls the protected method of its parent.

Comment: "In OOP, sooner or later, you are going to make a subclass of a class and in that case, it is good to understand and being able to modify the implementation completely." there's a whole truck-load of assumptions here, and I don't agree with either of them. why do you think this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Private by community"? :)

Comment: Python's convention is "we're all consenting adults here". I can honestly say that I've never been in a situation where I've thought, "Boy, I'm *so* glad they made that variable private!" On the other hand I've had several instances where a developer decided that a variable should be private because information hiding!!11!1! And my life was made more difficult.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Because as you say, `protected` still leaves you with the ability to "modify the implementation completely". It doesn't genuinely protect anything inside the class.

Why do we care about "genuinely protecting" the stuff inside the class? Because otherwise **it would be impossible to change implementation details without breaking client code**. Put another way, people who write subclasses are also "the outer world" for the person who wrote the original base class.

In practice, `protected` members are essentially a class' "public API for subclasses" and need to remain stable and backwards compatible just as much as `public` members do. If we did not have the ability to create true `private` members, then *nothing* in an implementation would ever be safe to change, because you wouldn't be able to rule out the possibility that (non-malicious) client code has somehow managed to depend on it.

Incidentally, while "In OOP, sooner or later, you are going to make a subclass of a class" is technically true, your argument seems to be making the much stronger assumption that "sooner or later, you are going to make a subclass of *every* class" which is almost certainly not the case.

Comment: I'd toss you more than +1 if I could, as this is the first time `private` ever actually made sense to me. The lib perspective needs to be used more often, otherwise anyone fond of the (C-like) "absolute control, absolute responsibility" coding mentality might flag it as "protects me from myself". Note that I still used `private` previously, I just always felt good documentation and a naming convention like `_foo` to indicate you probably shouldn't be messing with it was equivalent if not better. Being able to deterministically say "nothing will break" is a legitimate, `private`-only feature.

Comment: I originally ignored the case of the code of public libraries and frameworks and thought more or less only in terms of "client code". Optimizing the internal implementation is a good example for my question, though I ask myself, if this really happens in reality (especially when many people recommend a class should not be longer than 1000 lines of code). Generally, I like the Ruby's approach, where private is kind of a recommendation: "Here be dragons, proceed with care".

Comment: @AdamLibuša While this is a much bigger deal if your code is public, it still applies even if you're the author of all of the class' clients. The problem simply changes from certain refactors being *impossible* to certain refactors being tedious and error-prone. Optimization is actually the least common reason for these refactors in my experience (though I mainly do Javascript), usually it's more like a bug that exposed a fundamental implementation flaw which requires restructuring the dependency/call graph of the various internal bits in order to achieve a truly robust fix.

Comment: ""sooner or later, you are going to make a subclass of every class" is almost certainly not the case." And more to the point, you will almost certainly not, and you SHOULD certainly not, override every function in a class, and change the usage of every data element in a class. Some things should logically be written in stone for the class to have any meaning.

Comment: *I'd toss you more than +1 if I could* => That's what we call bounty @abluejelly

Comment: @Ixrec, I lost you when trying to understand the bolded sentence. And the follow-up sentence.  Can you give a more concrete example?   Are you saying that if we don't have `private` (only `protected`), we are... unable to add our own class functions/methods with the same name?

Comment: @Dennis Well, really the question is can you come up with any change that is backwards compatible in the strictest possible sense without using `private` anywhere. As far as I know, for every possible code change without `private` it's trivial to come up with some client code that would be broken by it. For instance, adding a non-private thing named `foo` becomes backwards-incompatible as soon as anybody writes a subclass with a thing named `foo`.

Answer (score 260):

> In OOP, sooner or later, you are going to make a subclass of a class

This is wrong. Not every class is meant to be subclassed and some statically typed OOP languages even have features to prevent it, e.g., `final` (Java and C++) or `sealed` (C#).

> it is good to understand and being able to modify the implementation completely.

No, it's not. It's good for a class to be able to clearly define its public interface and preserve its invariants even if it is inherited from.

In general, access control is about compartmentalization. You want an individual part of the code to be understood without having to understand in detail how it interacts with the rest of the code. Private access allows that. If everything is at least protected, you have to understand what every subclass does in order to understand how the base class works.

Or to put it in the terms of Scott Meyers: private parts of a class are affected by a finite amount of code: the code of the class itself.

Public parts are potentially affected by every bit of code in existence, and every bit of code yet to be written, which is an infinite amount of code.

Protected parts are potentially affected by every existing subclass, and every subclass yet to be written, which is also an infinite amount of code.

The conclusion is that protected gives you very little more than public, whereas private gives you a real improvement. It is the existence of the protected access specifier that is questionable, not private.

Comment: +1 for the theoretical scenario of "affected by an infinite amount of code"

Comment: Perhaps worth noting as well that the C# designers actually decided to prohibit overriding an inherited method unless it's explicitly marked as `virtual`, for the reasons outlined in this answer.

Comment: Or put simply: `protected` is for methods, not for data members.

Comment: I can't find it now, but I remember reading a well written answer from @EricLippert about why MS `sealed` big parts of .net's library and IIRC why he'd've liked to've locked the rest up.  The moment you allow 3rd party inheritors to start touching internal values you need to add a huge amount of validation/sanity checks to every method because you can no longer trust any design invariants about the objects internal state.

Comment: Protected should not be questionable at all. Patterns like Template rely on it and are quite useful

Comment: @LuisMasuelli He probably means a protected member/method is questionable in the same way that a public one is, i.e. you should always question why it needs to be non-private.

Comment: @Broken_Window In my mind that part was read in the voice of Douglas Adams (with bonus side remarks in HHGttG style).

Comment: @DanNeely - I think it was on SO, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3118480/188535).

Comment: protected is an easy way to make classes testable.   Java would benefit from a mechanism that gave test classes access while developing but not when released.

Comment: Inheritance is vastly overrated. The amount of textbook space devoted to inheritance is grossly out of proportion to the actual need for inheritance. All the arguments in the answers favoring composition over inheritance should be used as antidote for all the intellectual poison of the textbooks.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen "while developing but not when released" - how on earth is a class supposed to know? Do you really want to compile a test version that is different from the released version when you can't even test the release version? Tests shouldn't need to access private stuff anyway.

Comment: @DanNeely And it also means that more of the class becomes part of the public interface, and thus frozen in time forever. This can severely limit the changes you can make to the base class in the future, and the other classes that depend on that class. It's similar to why so much of the C language is undefined - it gives much more flexibility to the compiler writers and the hardware designers etc., and as long as you keep to the defined parts, you're "safe". Another example of "keep the public interface small". That said, I have yet to see a substantial C app that's 100% defined :D

Comment: @SebastianRedl the JVM knows.  And occasionally you need to access very private stuff if e.g. you need to see if the value you need hidden deep in a third party component is set correctly.   So, instead of just saying "its useless and there is no need" think outside the box.  In a perfect world we don't even need tests.

Comment: Well, that's what reflection and makeAccessible() are for.

Comment: @detly  That wasn't what I was looking for.  The one I was thinking of had Eric advocating for sealing up entire classes because once you let anything be changed by an inheritor you can't trust any bit of the internal state to not be screwed up in any of your functions.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I think you misunderstood the first quote.  The quote indicates that you will need to make at least one subclass from one method.  It is not trying to assert that all classes will need a subclass.

Comment: @Trisped What do you mean by "make at least one subclass from one method"? I don't understand what making subclasses from methods should be.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Sorry, should have been class, not method.  Trying to do too much at once.

Comment: "some statically typed OOP languages even have features to prevent it" - This isn't anything to do with a language being "statically typed". PHP, for instance, has the `final` keyword too, preventing class inheritance.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I don't see how _Not every class is meant to be subclassed_ disproves or is even referring to the statement _In OOP, sooner or later, you are going to make a subclass of a class_

Comment: @TheAnathema In the context of the claim that `protected` should always be used over `private`, the statement *sooner or later, you are going to make a subclass of a class* has to use "a class" in the sense of "every class", else it is not in support of the claim in the first place.

Answer (score 35):

Yes, private fields are absolutely necessary. Just this week I needed to write a custom dictionary implementation where I controlled what was put into the dictionary. If the dictionary field were to be made protected or public, then the controls I'd so carefully written could have been easily circumvented.

Private fields are typically about providing safeguards that the data is as the original coder expected. Make everything protected/public and you ride a coach and horses through those procedures and validation.

Comment: +1 for a real case example

Comment: +1 for "ride a coach and horses through" anything. It's a great phrase that I wish I heard more.

Comment: If somebody needs to subclass your class, perhaps he should have access to your safeguards? And if you don't want somebody to change your safeguards to achieve some goal, perhaps don't share the code? It works like this in Ruby - private is more or less of a recommendation.

Comment: @AdamLibuša "Don't share the code"? As soon as you publish any DLL at all, you're sharing the code - all the structures and methods and everything are there for the whole world to see, *especially* with languages that support reflection by default. Everyone can do whatever they want with "your code" - `private` is just a way of saying "don't touch these", and have it enforced within the compiler contract. In systems like .NET, this also has important security implications - you can only touch others' privates when you have full trust (basically the equivalent of admin/root access).

Comment: @AdamLibuša I think your confusion mainly stems from the different OOP approaches different languages took. The root of OOP (as originally defined) is *messaging* - that means that *everything* is private, except for the messages you respond to. In most OOPish languages, this is exposed as "keep your data private" - a way to make the public interface as small as possible. The only way the user (be it a subclass or another class) has to manipulate your class is through the public interface you defined - similar to how you usually use the steering wheel and pedals to drive your car :)

Comment: @Luaan +1 for when it's okay to touch others' privates!

Comment: because getting fields using stuff like reflection is so hard. Sorry, but you can already ride a coach, horses and even a train through anything.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html

And I haven't even mentioned how private variables can be circumvented in python where the only thing stopping anyone from accessing anything is just writing two underscores in front of whatever they want to access.

At the end of the day, "private" isn't really private. It's "public with a warning sign that this should not be used by the public".

Comment: Reflection is part of the standard Java API. How is it anything other than "vanilla"?

Comment: I never said reflection was a great idea. I was merely stating the fact that it is there. Private variables in java are not private in the sense people think. It just has a label that says "please don't touch my stuff" on it. There are no safeguards just because someone slapped on a private keyword on to a variable.

Comment: Well, I thought it was pretty obvious but apparently not. "Private fields are typically about providing safeguards that the data is as the original coder expected. " <- not true, as I've quite plainly explained.

Comment: Nothing "hobby" about Java, and I said nothing about circumventing my own safeguards (why would I want to do that). You claim that any user (another coder who uses the implementation) could be certain that your hashmap implementation was behaving as intended. There is absolutely nothing to stop some random malicious coder from supplying a library that uses your implementation and puts some malicious code in it. The person who uses this library (containing your implementation) can *not* expect it to behave like you intended. They are at the mercy of the library, not you.

Comment: Please show me *one* language where using the private access modifier on a variable ensures that it can never be changed by anything other than the original class. I don't have any axe to grind about security. I'm pointing out that access modifiers are there to convey intent, not actual access. There's a huge difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41033/discussion-between-robbie-dee-and-arnab-datta).

Comment: If code is shared, and you feel it’s a good idea to change the base class I wrote (and sometimes it is), from that point in you have full responsibility for the class.

Answer (score 13):

When attempting to reason formally [about the correctness of an Object Oriented program](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=619797) it is [typical](http://se.ethz.ch/~meyer/publications/computer/contract.pdf) to use a modular approach involving [object invariants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8902410/72810). In this approach

1. Methods have associated with them pre and post conditions (contracts).
2. Objects have associated with them invariants.

Modular reasoning about an object proceeds as follows (to a first a approximation at least)

1. Prove that the object's constructor establishes the invariant
2. For each non-private method, assume the object invariant and method precondition hold on entry, then prove that the body of the code implies that the postcondition and invariant hold on method exit

Imagine that we verify an `object A` using the approach above. And now wish to verify `method g` of `object B` which calls `method f` of `object A`. Modular reasoning allows us to reason about `method g` without having to reconsider the implementation of `method f`. Provided we can establish the invariant of `object A` and precondition of `method f` at the call site in `method g,` we can take the post condition of `method f` as a summary of the behaviour of the method call. Moreover we will also know that after the call returns the invariant of `A` still holds.

This modularity of reasoning is what allow us to think formally about large programs. We can reason about each of the methods individually and then compose the results of this reasoning in turn to reason about larger parts of the program.

**Private fields** are very useful in this process. In order to know that the invariant of an object continues to hold between two method calls on that object, we typically rely on the fact that the object is not modified in the intervening period.

For modular reasoning to work in a context where objects do not have private fields then we would have to have some way to ensure that whatever a field happened to be set to by another object, that the invariant was always re-established (after the field set). It is difficult to imagine an object invariant that both holds no matter what value the object's fields have, and is also useful in reasoning about the program's correctness. We would probably have to invent some complicated convention around field access. And probably also lose some of (at worst even all of) our ability to reason modularly.

**Protected fields**

Protected fields restore some of our ability to reason modularly. Depending on the language `protected` may restrict the ability to set a field to all subclasses or all subclasses and same-package classes. It is often the case that we do not have access to all subclasses when we are reasoning about the correctness of an object we are writing. For example, you might be writing a component or library that will later be used in a larger program (or several larger programs) — some of which may not even have been written yet. Typically you will not know if and in what ways it may be sub-classed.

However, it is usually incumbent on a subclass to maintain the object invariant of the class it extends. So, in a language where protect means "sub-class" only, and where we are disciplined to ensure that sub-classes always maintain the invariants of their superclass, you could argue that the choice of using protected instead of private loses only minimal modularity.

Although I have been talking about formal reasoning, it is [often thought](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1243380) that when programmers informal reason about the correctness of their code they also sometimes rely on similar types of arguments.

Answer (score 9):

`private` variables in a class are better than `protected` for the same reason that a `break` statement inside a `switch` block is better than a `goto label` statement; which is that *human programmers* are error-prone.

`protected` variables lend themselves to un-intentional abuse (programmer mistakes), just as the `goto` statement lends itself to the creation of spaghetti code.

Is it possible to write working bug-free code using `protected` class variables?  Yes of course! Just as it's possible to write working bug-free code using `goto`; but as the cliche goes ***"Just because you can, doesn't mean you should!"***

Classes, and indeed the OO paradigm, exist to guard against hapless error-prone human programmers making mistakes.   The defense against human mistakes is only as good as the defensive measures built into the class.   Making the implementation of your class `protected` is the equivalent of blowing an enormous hole in the walls of a fortress.

Base classes have absolutely no knowledge of derived classes.   As far as a base class is concerned, `protected` does not actually give you any more protection than `public`, because there's nothing stopping a derived class from creating a `public` getter/setter which behaves like a backdoor.

If a base class permits un-hindered access to its internal implementation details, then it becomes impossible for the class itself to defend against mistakes. Base classes have absolutely no knowledge of their derived classes, and therefore have no way of guarding against mistakes made in those derived classes.

The best thing a base class can do is hide as much of its implementation as possible as `private` and put enough restrictions in place to guard against breaking changes from derived classes or anything else outside of the class.

Ultimately, high-level languages exist to minimise human errors.   Good programming practises (such as [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))) also exist to minimise human errors.

Software developers who ignore good programming practices have a much higher chance of failure, and are more likely to produce broken unmaintainable solutions.   Those who follow good practices have a much lower chance of failure, and are more likely to produce working maintainable solutions.

Comment: To downvoter - what could be changed/improved about this answer?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but comparing access level with break/goto?

Comment: @imel96 No, comparing the reason why they are avoided, and are discouraged by "Best practise" (particularly for writing *new* code).    i.e. A competent programmer would avoid `public` implementation details because it lends itself to unmaintainable code.    A competent programmer would avoid `goto` because it lends itself to unmaintainable code.     However the real world is such that sometimes you are lost in a terrible mess of legacy code, and have no choice but to use `goto`, and for that same reason you sometimes have no choice but to use public/protected implementation details.

Comment: The severity is different in magnitude, it's incomparable. I could live with code that only have `public` properties/interface, but not with code that only uses `goto`.

Comment: @imel96 Then you either over-estimate the severity of `goto` or under-estimate the severity of having classes whose data is all exposed publicly.    Both are common causes of ending up with spaghetti code; it's just that there are a lot more people out in the world who lack understanding of encapsulation and write a lot of bad code with all their data members being `public`.    Similarly, there are a lot of legacy codebases out there which already use `goto` and when you work in that code, you tend to be faced with no choice but to continue using it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful is well known and I haven't found anything else raised to that level. Even non-OOP is not considered harmful!

Comment: @imel96 Have you ever actually worked in code which uses `goto` or is it just because you've read articles like that?    I understand **why** `goto` is evil because I've spent 2 years working in ancient code which uses it; and I have spent even longer working in code where "classes" have their implementation details leaked everywhere with `public` and `friend` specifiers used as quick/easy/dirty hacks.     I don't accept the argument that "exposing implementation details publicly" can't cause an inter-twined spaghetti mess at the same level of severity as `goto` because it absolutely can.

Answer (score 4):

Inheritable classes have two contracts--one with holders of object references, and with derived classes.  Public members are bound by the contract with reference holders, and protected members are bound by the contract with derived classes.

Making members `protected` makes it a more versatile base class, but will often limit the ways in which future versions of the class might change.  Making members `private` allows the class author more versatility to change the inner workings of the class, but limits the kinds of classes that can be usefully derived from it.

As an example, `List<T>` in .NET makes the backing store private; if it were protected, derived types could do some useful things that are otherwise not possible, but future versions of `List<T>` would forevermore have to use its clunky monolithic backing store even for lists holding millions of items.  Making the backing store private would allow future versions of `List<T>` to use a more efficient backing store without breaking derived classes.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a key assumption in your argument that **when someone writes a class they don't know who might extend that class down the road and for what reason**.  Given this assumption your argument would make perfect sense because every variable you make private then could potentially cut off some avenue of development down the road.  However, I would reject that assumption.

*If that assumption is rejected then there are only two cases to consider.*

1. The author of the original class had very clear ideas for why it might be extended (e.g. it is a BaseFoo and there will be several concrete Foo implementations down the road).

In this case, the author knows that someone will be extending the class and why and therefore will know exactly what to make protected and what to make private.  They are using the private/protected distinction to communicate an interface of sorts to the user creating the subclass.

2. The author of the child class is trying to hack in some behavior into a parent class.

This case should be rare (you could argue it isn't legitimate), and is not preferred to just modifying the original class in the original code base.  It could also be a symptom of bad design.  In those cases I would prefer the person hacking in the behavior just use other hacks like friends (C/C++) and `setAccessible(true)` (Java).

*I think it is safe to reject that assumption.*

This generally falls back to the idea of [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).  Inheritance is often taught as an ideal way to reduce code reuse however it should rarely be the first choice for code reuse.  I don't have a simple knock-down argument and it can be a fairly difficult and contentious to understand.  However, in my experience with domain modeling I have found that I rarely use inheritance without having a very clear understanding of who will be inheriting my class and why.

Answer (score 3):

All three access levels have their use case, OOP would be incomplete lacking any of them. Usually you do

- make all variables/data members **private**. You don't want someone from outside to mess with your internal data. Also methods that provide auxiliary functionality (think calculations based on several member variables) to your *public* or *protected* interface - this is only for internal use, and you might want to change/improve it in the future.
- make the general interface of your class **public**. That's what the users of your original class are supposed to work with, and how you think derived classes should look like, too. In order to provide proper encapsulation these are usually only methods (and helper classes/structs, enums, typedefs, whatever the user needs to work with your methods), not variables.
- declare the methods **protected** that could be of use for someone who wants to extend/specialize the functionality of your class, but should not be part of the *public* interface - in fact you usually raise *private* members to *protected* when necessary. If in doubt you don't, until you know that

  1. your class can/may/will be subclassed,
  2. and have a clear idea what the use cases of subclassing may be.

And you deviate from this general scheme only if there's a **good reason™**. Beware of "this will make my life easier when I can freely access it from outside" (and *outside* here also includes subclasses). When I implement class hierarchies I often start with classes that don't have protected members, until I come to subclassing/extending/specializing them, becoming the base classes of a framework/toolkit and sometimes moving part of their original functionality one level up.

Answer (score 1):

A more interesting question, perhaps, is why any other type of field than private is necessary. When a subclass needs to interact with the data of a superclass, doing so directly creates a direct coupling between the two, whereas using methods to provide for the interaction between the two allows a level of indirection that can make it possible to make changes to the superclass that would otherwise be very difficult.

A number of languages (e.g. Ruby and Smalltalk) do not provide public fields so that developers are discouraged from allowing direct coupling to their class implementations, but why not go further and only have private fields? There would be no loss of generality (because the superclass can always provide protected accessors  for the subclass), but it would ensure that classes always have at least a small degree of isolation from their subclasses. Why is this not a more common design?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of good answers here, but I'll throw in my two cents anyway. :-)

Private is good for the same reason that global data is bad.

If a class declares data private, then you absolutely know that the only code messing with this data is the code in the class. When there's a bug, you don't have to search all over creation to find every place that might change this data. You know it's in the class. When you make a change to the code, and you change something about how this field is used, you don't have to track down all the potential places that might use this field and study whether your planned change will break them. You know the only places are inside the class.

I have had many, many times that I have had to make changes to classes that are in a library and used by multiple apps, and I have to tread very carefully to make sure I don't break some app that I know nothing about. The more public and protected data there is, the more potential for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth to mention some dissenting opinions.

In theory, it's good to have controlled access level for all the reasons mentioned in other answers.

In practice, too often when code reviewing, I see people (who like to use private), changing access level from private -> protected and not too often from protected -> public. Almost always, changing class properties involve modifying setters/getters. These have wasted much of my time (code review) and theirs (changing code).

It also annoys me that that means their classes are not Closed for modification.

That was with internal code where you can always change it if you need too. The situation is worse with 3rd party code when it's not so easy to change code.

So how many programmers think it's a hassle? Well, how many are using programming languages that don't have private? Of course, people are not just using those languages because they don't have private specifiers, but it helps to simplify the languages and simplicity is important.

Imo it's very similar to dynamic/static typing. In theory, static typing is very good. In practice, it only prevents like 2% of errors [The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Dynamic Typing ...](http://games.greggman.com/game/dynamic-typing-static-typing/). Using private probably prevents error less than that.

I think SOLID principles are good, I wish people care about them more than they care about creating a class with public, protected and private.

Comment: If you need to change 3rd party code when using it, either it is not well designed, either you are not reusing it well. You can always reuse a non-abstract class by encapsulating it, but in practice you hardly ever need to subclass it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like to add another practical example of why `protected` is not enough. At my university the first years undertake a project where they have to develop a desktop version of a board game (that later an AI is developed for and it is connected to other players over a network). Some partial code is provided to them to get them started including a testing framework. Some of the properties of the main game class are exposed as `protected` so that the test classes that extend this class have access to them. But these fields aren't sensitive information.

As a TA for the unit I often see students simply making all their added code `protected` or `public` (perhaps because they saw the other `protected` and `public` stuff and assumed they should follow suit). I ask them why their protection level is inappropriate, and many don't know why. The answer is that the sensitive information that they are exposing to subclasses means that another player can cheat by simply extending that class and accessing the highly sensitive information for the game (essentially the opponents hidden location, I guess similar to how it would be if you could see your opponents pieces on a battleships board by extending some class). That makes their code very dangerous in the context of the game.

Other than that, there are many other reasons to keep something private to even your subclasses. It might be to hide implementation details that could mess up the correct working of the class if changed by someone who doesn't necessarily know what they are doing (mostly thinking about other people using your code here).

Comment: I don't understand. Unless players are dynamically extending classes while the game is running, how could this be used to cheat? This would imply that you're importing untrusted code into your codebase. If you are saying that you giving students compiled classes and preventing them from cheating in their assignment by modifying implementation details, setting a protection level isn't going to make the assignment any more secure. Students can decompile libraries or use reflection to their advantage. This of course depends on the level of enforcement you are after.

Comment: @sam Generally code should be written with the assumption that whoever modifies it next won't need to know the entire codebase inside out. That could even be the original author at times (time passing, lack of sleep...). Cheating could be students being given skeleton code to flesh out, and changing logic they shouldn't touch.

Answer (score 0):

Private methods/variables will generally be hidden from a subclass. That can be a good thing.

A private method can make assumptions about parameters and leave sanity checking to the caller.

A protected method *should* sanity check inputs.

Answer (score -1):

> One of the first things I do when I subclass a class is to change a
>   bunch of private methods to protected

Some reasoning about `private` vs. `protected` **methods**:

`private` methods prevent code reuse. A subclass cannot use the code in the private method and may have to implement it again - or re-implement the method(s) which originally depend on the private method &c.

On the other hand, any method which is *not* `private` can be seen as an API provided by the class to "the outer world", in the sense that third-party subclasses are considered "outer world" too, as someone else suggested in his answer already.

Is that a bad thing? - I don't think so.

Of course, a (pseudo-)public API locks the original programmer up and hinders refactoring of those interfaces. But seen the other way around, why should a programmer not design his own "implementation details" in a way that's as clean and stable as his public API? Should he use `private` so that he can be sloppy about structuring his "private" code? Thinking maybe that he could clean it up later, because no one will notice? - No.

The programmer should put a little thought into his "private" code too, to structure it in a way that allows or even promotes reuse of as much of it as possible in the first place. Then the non-private parts may not become as much of a burden in the future as some fear.

A lot of (framework) code I see adopts an inconsistent use of `private`: `protected`, non-final methods which barely do anything more than delegating to a private method is commonly found. `protected`, non-final methods whose contract can only be fulfilled through direct access to private fields too.

These methods cannot logically be overridden/enhanced, although technically there's nothing there to make that (compiler-)obvious.

Want extendability and inheritance? Don't make your methods `private`.

Don't want certain behavior of your class altered? Make your methods `final`.

Really cannot have your method called outside of a certain, well-defined context? Make your method `private` and/or think about how you can make the required well-defined context available for reuse through another `protected` wrapper method.

That's why I advocate to use `private` sparingly. And to not confuse `private` with `final`. - If a method's implementation is vital to the general contract of the class and thus is must not be replaced/overridden, make it `final`!

For fields, `private` is not really bad. As long as the field(s) can be reasonably "used" via appropriate methods (that's *not* `getXX()` or `setXX()`!).

Comment: -1 This doesn't address the `private` vs `protected` original question, gives mistaken advice ("use `private` sparingly"?) and goes against the general consensus on OO design. Using `private` has nothing to do with hiding sloppy code.

Comment: You mention that a class has an API, but don't seem to make the connection that the user of the API does not want to be burdened with details that they don't need to know.    The ideal situation for the user of a class is for the interface to contain only the methods they need, and nothing else.   Making methods `private` helps to keep the API clean.

Comment: @AndreasF. My advice is certainly not mistaken, but your comment leads me to ask: Then when do you use protected? And yes, most programmers do use private to make their life easier without fully thinking it through.

Comment: @BenCottrell You say "the methods they need", and that is the problem. How do you know which methods a future subclass may want to reuse or override?  Apparently I did not make myself clear enough because from the comments and downvotes I feel that my point didn't quite get through. I think I'll let my answer stand as it is for now though because elaborating would mainly repeat the other answers already given. If someone got my point and has a suggestion for improvement I'd love to edit it in.

Comment: @AndreasF. How does my answer not address the question "is private useful", when I state in which case it is or is not useful?

Comment: @HannoBinder It is the responsibility for somebody writing a class to decide how that class can and cannot be used so they can prevent it from being mis-used in ways which had not been originally intended.    The author of a class will always know which methods a future subclass can reuse or override because it is their responsibility as designer to ensure that class is well behaved when it is reused and when those elements of that class are reused and overridden.

Comment: @BenCottrell I fully agree with you. Except that I'd say "the author of a class **should** know...". And from my experience, people often do *not* correccly anticipate possible valid future uses of their classes. That's e.g. when a class will output to console or files, but just cannot be made to output to a network stream, through subclassing or any other means.

Comment: @HannoBinder I agree that there are plenty of classes out there which suffer from rigidity, however flexibility and code reuse are much less important than encapsulation and long-term maintainability.   Consider your case where all classes have protected members and derived classes can mess about with any implementation details they desire; how do you reliably unit test those classes knowing that anything in any part of yet-unwritten code could cause that code to fail at any time?  how many such "hacks" could the code take before it all degenerates into a big ball of mud?

Comment: @BenCottrell I tend to argue in the opposite direction: Each method has a *contract* to fulfil. How it goes about that does not relly matter, so as long as the contract remains fulfilled anyone may override my method with any novel implementation he sees fit. My tests test my code. Future extensions must be tested by whoever is responsible for them, in addition to my tests. Of course, altering a method's contract in a subclass is not a valid change and whoever implements the override must consider that or things break. Yet, in Java, we have `final` that can be used in combination with any

Comment: visibility, and I ecourage people to not use `private` when in fact they mean `final`.

Comment: Oh, you said "members". What I'm saying is referring to *methods* only. Member variables (fields) is a different story, where privacy is much more justified.

Comment: The nomenclature in the discussion is all over the place because it is not specific to a particular language. "Member" in C++ can be data, function, type, or template.

Comment: @HannoBinder indeed, at this point I think we have been talking past each other - I inferred from the question that the issue is around data members/member variables rather than Methods.   I have no issue around protected methods, and I find that classes which adhere to "SOLID" (particularly SRP) tend to have few methods which are either protected or private anyway.

Answer (score -1):

"private" means: Not intended to be changed or accessed by anyone except the class itself. Not intended to be changed or accessed by subclasses. Subclasses? What subclasses? You are not supposed to subclass this!

"protected" means: Only intended to be changed or accessed by classes or subclasses. Likely deduction that you are supposed to subclass, otherwise why "protected" and not "private"?

There's a clear difference here. If I make something private, you are supposed to keep your dirty fingers off it. Even if you are a subclass.

Answer (score -1):

> Do you know about an important use case where private instead of
>   protected is a good tool, or would two options "protected & public" be
>   enough for OOP languages?

**Private**: when you have something that will never be useful for any subclass to call or override.

**Protected**: when you have something that has a subclass-specific implementation/constant.

An example:

```
public abstract Class MercedesBenz() extends Car {
  //Might be useful for subclasses to know about their customers
  protected Customer customer; 

  /* Each specific model has its own horn. 
     Therefore: protected, so that each subclass might implement it as they wish
  */
  protected abstract void honk();

  /* Taken from the car class. */
  @Override
  public void getTechSupport(){
     showMercedesBenzHQContactDetails(customer);
     automaticallyNotifyLocalDealer(customer);
  }

  /* 
     This isn't specific for any subclass.
     It is also not useful to call this from inside a subclass,
     because local dealers only want to be notified when a 
     customer wants tech support. 
   */
  private void automaticallyNotifyLocalDealer(){
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: *when you have something that will never be useful for any subclass to call or override* – And this is something that you, in my opinion, never know in advance.

Comment: Well, I might also need to press the reset button on my CMOS. But the default assumption is that I won't really need it, and therefore it is put inside the chassis. The same goes for methods. You make it protected if the subclass absolutely needs to reimplement/call it (see: honking). You make it public if other parties need to call it.

Answer (score -2):

It was hard for me to understand this matter, so I'd like to share a piece of my experience :

- What is the **protected** field? It's **nothing more** than a field, that can't be accessed outside a class, i.e. *publically* like this: `$classInstance->field`. And the trick that it's "this is it". Your class' childrens will have a **full** access to it, because it's their rightful internal part.
- What is the **private** field? It's a "**true private**" for your very own class **and** your very own implementation of this class. "Keep out of reach of the children", just like on a medicine's bottle. You will have a guarantee that it's unoverridable by your class' derivatives, your methods - when called - will have **exact** what you've declared

UPDATE: a practical example by a real task I've solved. Here it is : you have a token, like USB or LPT(that was my case), and you have a middleware. The token asks you for a pincode, opens up if it's correct and you can send encrypted part and a number of key to decipher. The keys are stored in token, you can not read them, only use them. And there were *temporary* keys for a session, signed by a key in a token, but stored in a middleware itself. The temp key were not supposed to leak eveywhere outside, just to exist on a driver level. And I used a **private** fields to store this temporary key and some hardware-connection-related data. So no derivatives were able to use not just a public interface, but also some **protected** "handy" subroutines I've made for a task, but were unable to open a strongbox with the keys and HW interaction. Makes sense?

Comment: sorry guys! just messed them up - updating my answer =) THANKS! I was in a hurry and mistyped =)

Comment: I think the OP is aware of the differences between the two protection levels, but is interested in why one should be used over the other.

Comment: @Sam please take a deeper reading of my answer. They are **completely different** types of field! the **only** thing they have in common is that they both can not be referenced publically

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to. I'm aware of the differences between private and protected. Perhaps you mis-understood what I meant by protection levels? I'm referring to 'access level's. I was trying to point out that while your answer isn't bad, it doesn't directly address the question. The OP appears to know what both protected/private/public mean, but isn't sure under what circumstances they would want to choose one over the other. This may be way you are been voted down (not by me).

Comment: @Sam I think I've got your point - added a practical case from my real practice/experience. Is it what's missing on your point?